# Powershell Missing Cluster Name for FCI

Tags: sql-server, clustering, powershell

I'm running the following simple Powershell command.

```
$Server = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') 'SerName'
$Server | SELECT *
```

For FCI clusters the `ClusterName` value is always blank and the `ClusterQuorumState` and `ClusterQuorumType` are always `NotApplicable`.  `IsClustered` is set to True though.

If I run it against an Availability Group I get back the cluster name and the correct values for the other two properties.

Is there a way in Powershell to get the cluster name for the FCI instances?  Another cmdlet I can use?

Answer (score 1):

No need to load up the Smo object, you can query WMI to get this

```
gwmi -Query "select Name from cim_cluster" -namespace root\mscluster -computername [computername] | select Name
```

Comment: To keep code consistent for how I've been doing it so far, I haven't been using -query, would I call it like this?  "gwmi -Class CIM_Cluster -Namespace root\MSCluster -ComputerName [ComputerName]"  That works but I'm not sure if there is a class I can call without using the -namespace.